# Possible to re-name STL vector?

Tags: c++

I am working on a very big and old C++ project.  The word "vector" has been used all over the place. I am now trying to add new functionality to the project utilizing STL vector.  This is not working. In addition, I am only allowed to modify specific sections of the code, so I can not change their use of "vector".

Is there a way to rename STL vector and use it?

Comment: That's what namespaces are for, right?

Comment: Isn't that why `vector` is in namespace `std`?

Comment: Currently I have "using namespace std" at the top of the file.  Will things work if I use std::vector instead?

Comment: @user1247549: Yes, get rid of `using` and always qualify with `std::`, and you should be fine.

Comment: [related FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [C++ namespaces](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/).

```
#include <vector>

// note the absence of `using namespace std;` line

int main() {
    // note the `std::` qualification
    std::vector<int> x;

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As long as you **don't** put `using namespace std;` anywhere (which is not a great thing to do anyway), there will be no conflict between `::std::vector` and any other `vector`.

I'm assuming that this infinite wisdom didn't extend to declaring names inside `std`; in that case, my best advice is to run away. I'm also assuming that you're talking about the modern C++ library, not the STL which (I think) didn't have its own namespace.

Comment: I don't think the compiler would let you declare another vector in std.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: It will, if you don't include the library's declaration.

Comment: True, but then there's no conflict to speak of.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: There will be if you're given the task of adding code that needs to use `std::vector` - which is what the question is all about.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `using namespace std;` from the beginning of the file, and add `std::` in the code wherever is needed:

```
std::cout << "debug" << std::endl;
std::vector<std::string> simple_vector;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just refer to it using the full name `std::vector`.

In C++11, you could also use a [`using` statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Alias_templates).

Comment: You can use `using` prior to C++11 also.

Answer (score -1):

**Don't do this.**

```
#define vector stdVector
#include <vector>
#undef vector
```

**End of don't do this**

You can either use namespaces to qualify your version of `vector` or the one from `std`, after you remove the `using` directives.